# Wamp - Installed php5.2 Addon - Icon Stays Yellow

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I originally installed a recent version of wamp (php 5.3) but I need to use php 5.2 for my current project.  I downloaded the addon for php 5.2 and installed it.  Then I stop all services and in the wamp menu I do

PHP -> version -> 5.2.11

I restart.  Now wamp goes from red to yellow, but never goes from yellow to green. I don't see anything relevant in the apache error log. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this?

Thanks,
Jonah

Comment: For posterity: The answer to this problem is that 64bit wamp in incompatible with php5.2.  The solution is to reinstall wamp 32x.

Comment: Just in case someone has the same setup as me: when downgrading to php5.2 and then installing WAMP 32-bits on a 64-bit system, Apache 2.2.17 does not work either. Switching to 2.2.11 gives you a green icon in the end.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround.
You need to install 32bit Apache addon.
And use it to work with 32bit PHP.

Answer (score 0):

i managed the same situation, IIS uses the same port 80 or your old wamp server(it didn't uninstall correctly). if you can't unistall it. you should change wamp port in httpd.conf

1.find these lines :

```
 Listen 80
 ServerName localhost:80
```

2.change to

```
 Listen 81
  ServerName localhost:81
```

3.restart all services.

4.enter this address on your browser.
    localhost:81